# Validation with yup failed for generic react hook form component

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to make generic component for text input for react hook form.
Here is the link to sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-https-0osjz?file=/src/App.tsx
Problem is with validation and it started when I moved code to separate component.
What I did wrong here?
I suspect that I make some issue with TS as I am using it first time.

Comment: I don't think you saved your code sandbox. It is just a generic TS/React playground

Comment: Can you check now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is severals problems:

- you're using two `useForm` instead of one, that's why errors aren't displayed and form isn't submitted
- Controller need `control` props to work, you can get control from `useForm` and pass it down to child components or retrieve it with `useFormContext`

Your working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-alex-d7gpn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Ahhh I understand thanks. Do you think that I can maybe avoid using <FormProvider {...methods}> or it is required when making custom fields like this?

Comment: FormProvider isn't required if you don't `useFormContext`